# Electric field of cathode ray

Tags: electric-field

In my study book of radio frequency engineering is a question which is pretty odd in my opinion.

Calculate the electrical field of a cathode ray for the cases \$r < d\$ and \$r > d\$.

The two following conditions are given:

- Velocity as a function of radius
  \$ v_z =v_0 \cdot [1 - (\frac{r}{d})^3]\$
- Charge density
  \$ \rho = \rho_0 \cdot [ 1 + (\frac{r}{d})^2]\$

Can anyone tell my how to get to these conditions? There are no other mentions about them in this book. I tried to calculate the E-field with \$E = \frac{\rho}{2 \cdot \pi \cdot \epsilon \cdot r}\$ but I cannot figure out how to get a proper solution.

PS: I don't know which radius and what's meant with \$d\$. I hoped one of you can help me, maybe there's a known similar example.

Comment: What are \$ r \$ and \$ d \$? Was there a diagram in the book? "Radius"? What radius? Put the information into your question rather than in the comments.

Comment: My guess would be *d* is the distance between cathode and anode.

Comment: @Franz Please provide an attempt at the solution

Comment: This was five years ago, sorry. I don't even think that I find this study book again.